# get specific file content via node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I use the following code to get specific file which is located in my c folder,
my question is how to get specific content inside this file for example
i've text file and the content is

```
name:test 1 test2 test 3
user: foo bar
```

I need that when the file was read to get the `test1 test2 test3` as **"string"** when I find "key" of **name** in the text file.
How can I do that ?

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('c//myfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer will have issues when your value contains ':'. 
For example when your line is 'name: bla:bli:blub', you would only get 'bla' as a result.

So this is my suggestion that wont have that problem:

You could place this snippet into your readFile method:

```
var keyValueObject = {};
data.split("\n").forEach(function(element) {
    var keyValueSeperatorPosition = element.indexOf(':');
    var key = element.substr(0, keyValueSeperatorPosition);
    var value = element.substring(keyValueSeperatorPosition + 1);
    keyValueObject[key] = value;
});
```

You can then access your values using:

```
keyValueObject['name']
```

Comment: he is obviously talking about key value pairs. The behaviour of your answer does not have any other output than mine would :) your solution would struggle reading more than 1 line though ;)

Comment: still values could contain the character ':' which would discard everything coming after that in your snippet

Also my solution works fine with multiple lines O.o dont see why it would behave differently with multiple lines then yours as we are both splitting at newline and iterating over each line

Answer (score 0):

EDIT1:
done it a little more generic now. keyVals is now an array of objects with key and val pairs of your file

```
fs = require('fs')
var keyVals = [];
fs.readFile('c//myfile.txt', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    var lines = data.split('\n');

    lines.forEach(function(line){
      var pair = line.split(':');
      keyVals.push({key:pair[0],val:pair[1]});
    });
});
```

access it like this:

```
keyVals.forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element.key, element.value);
})
```

I hope this helps